# Mousemove and Hover Jquery effect to Pure Javascript or VueJS event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS component which is a svg map image of the united states. I previously used jquery to create hover effects to display the information bubble. I am trying to convert this to a pure Javascript solution. It seems a click event is the easiest to implement given vuejs mousemove seems to be less reliable. I have added the click event in method and I am trying to capture the SVG path location and steal the top and left position to enable the info box there. I have tried this.offsettop and this.offsetleft but they return undefined.

Jquery code I am trying to convert:

```
$("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');   
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

VueJS Component

```
<template id="geomap-assignments">
    <v-card class="pa-4 ma-3 rounded-lg" min-height="500px">
        <div class="card-title-docs">
            <h4 class="card-header">Assignments</h4>
            <h5 class="card-sub-header"></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="map-container">
            <div id="info-box"></div>
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <svg xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="Republican_Party_presidential_primaries_results,_2016.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
            <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
            </sodipodi:namedview>
            <g id="g5">
                    <path id="HI" data-info="<div>State: Hawaii</div><div>Capital: Honolulu</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z" />
                    <path id="OK" data-info="<div>State: Oklahoma</div><div>Capital: Oklahoma City</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M549.3,422.6l-10.7-0.5l-6.4-0.5l0.3,0.2l-0.7,10.4l22,1.4l32.1,1.3l-2.3,24.4l-0.5,17.8l0.2,1.6   l4.3,3.7l2.1,1.1l0.7-0.2l0.7-2.1l1.4,1.8h2.1v-1.4l2.7,1.4l-0.5,3.9l4.1,0.2l2.5,1.1l4.1,0.7l2.5,1.8l2.3-2.1l3.4,0.7l2.5,3.4h0.9   v2.3l2.3,0.7l2.3-2.3l1.8,0.7h2.5l0.9,2.5l4.8,1.8l1.4-0.7l1.8-4.1h1.1l1.1,2.1l4.1,0.7l3.7,1.4l3,0.9l1.8-0.9l0.7-2.5h4.3l2.1,0.9   l2.7-2.1h1.1l0.7,1.6h4.1l1.6-2.1l1.8,0.5l2.1,2.5l3.2,1.8l3.2,0.9l1.9,1.1l-0.4-37.2l-1.4-11l-0.2-8.9l-1.4-6.5l-0.8-7.2l-0.1-3.8   l-12.1,0.3l-46.4-0.5l-45-2.1L549.3,422.6z" />
                    <path id="KS" data-info="<div>State: Kansas</div><div>Capital: Topeka</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M677.4,425.1l-12.6,0.2l-46.1-0.5l-44.6-2.1l-24.6-1.3l4.1-64.7l21.8,0.8l40.5,1.4l44.1,0.5h5.1   l3.2,3.2l2.8,0.2l0.9,1.1v2l-1.8,1.6l-0.5,2.6l2.2,3.6l2.5,3.1l2.5,2l1.1,11.2L677.4,425.1z" />
                    <path id="LA" data-info="<div>State: Louisiana</div><div>Capital: Baton Rouge</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M776.2,573l-1-2.6l-1.1-3.1l-3.3-3.5l0.9-6.8l-0.1-1.1l-1.3,0.3l-8.2,0.9l-25,0.5l-0.7-2.4l0.9-8.5   l3.3-5.9l5-8.7l-0.6-2.4l1.3-0.7l0.5-2l-2.3-2.1l-0.1-1.9l-1.8-4.3l-0.5-5.9l-9.7,0.1l-19.2,0.9l-22.2,0l0,9.6l0.7,9.4l0.7,3.9   l2.5,4.1l0.9,5l4.3,5.5l0.2,3.2l0.7,0.7l-0.7,8.5l-3,5l1.6,2.1l-0.7,2.5l-0.7,7.3l-1.4,3.2l0.1,3.6l4.7-1.5l8.1-0.3l10.3,3.6   l6.5,1.1l3.7-1.5l3.2,1.1l3.2,1l0.8-2.1l-3.2-1.1l-2.6,0.5l-2.7-1.6c0,0,0.2-1.3,0.8-1.5c0.6-0.2,3.1-1,3.1-1l1.8,1.5l1.8-1   l3.2,0.6l1.5,2.4l0.3,2.3l4.5,0.3l1.8,1.8l-0.8,1.6l-1.3,0.8l1.6,1.6l8.4,3.6l3.6-1.3l1-2.4l2.6-0.6l1.8-1.5l1.3,1l0.8,2.9   l-2.3,0.8l0.6,0.6l3.4-1.3l2.3-3.4l0.8-0.5l-2.1-0.3l0.8-1.6l-0.2-1.5l2.1-0.5l1.1-1.3l0.6,0.8c0,0-0.2,3.1,0.6,3.1   c0.8,0,4.2,0.6,4.2,0.6l4,1.9l1,1.5h2.9l1.1,1l2.3-3.1v-1.5h-1.3l-3.4-2.7l-5.8-0.8l-3.2-2.3l1.1-2.7l2.3,0.3l0.2-0.6l-1.8-1v-0.5   h3.2l1.8-3.1l-1.3-1.9l-0.3-2.7l-1.5,0.2l-1.9,2.1l-0.6,2.6l-3.1-0.6l-1-1.8l1.8-1.9l2-1.8L776.2,573z" />
                    <path id="VA" data-info="<div>State: Virginia</div><div>Capital: Richmond</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M1002.9,369.2l-0.1-1.9l6.5-2.5l-0.8,3.2l-2.9,3.8l-0.4,4.6l0.5,3.4l-1.8,5l-2.2,1.9l-1.5-4.6   l0.4-5.4l1.6-4.2L1002.9,369.2z M1005.2,397.5L947,410.1l-37.4,5.3l-6.7-0.4l-2.6,1.9l-7.3,0.2l-8.4,1l-8.9,1l8.5-4.9l0-2.1   l1.5-2.1l10.6-11.5l3.9,4.5l3.8,1l2.5-1.1l2.2-1.3l2.5,1.3l3.9-1.4l1.9-4.6l2.6,0.5l2.9-2.1l1.8,0.5l2.8-3.7l0.3-2.1l-1-1.3l1-1.9   l5.3-12.3l0.6-5.7l1.2-0.5l2.2,2.4l3.9-0.3l1.9-7.6l2.8-0.6l1-2.7l2.6-2.3l1.3-2.3l1.5-3.4l0.1-5.1l9.8,3.8   c0.7,0.3,0.7-4.8,0.7-4.8l4.1,1.4l-0.5,2.6l8.2,2.9l1.3,1.8l-0.9,3.7l-1.3,1.3l-0.5,1.7l0.5,2.4l2,1.3l3.9,1.4l2.9,1l4.9,0.9   l2.2,2.1l3.2,0.4l0.9,1.2l-0.4,4.7l1.4,1.1l-0.5,1.9l1.2,0.8l-0.2,1.4l-2.7-0.1l0.1,1.6l2.3,1.5l0.1,1.4l1.8,1.8l0.5,2.5l-2.6,1.4   l1.6,1.5l5.8-1.7L1005.2,397.5z" />
                    <g id="DC">
                    <path id="path58" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M975.8,353.8l-1.1-1.6l-1-0.8l1.1-1.6l2.2,1.5L975.8,353.8z" />
                    <circle id="circle60" data-info="<div>Washington DC</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.5" cx="975.3" cy="351.8" r="5" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <path id="path67" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M385,593v55l36,45 M174,525h144l67,68h86l53,54v46" />

        </svg>
        </div>
    </v-card>
</template>
<script>
    Vue.component('geomap-assignments', {
        template: '#geomap-assignments',

        methods: {
            activateCaption: function (event) {
                // `event` is the native DOM event
                if (event) {
                    const left = this.offsetTop
                    const top = this.offsetTop
                    alert("LEFT" + left + "RIGHT" + top);
                }
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                documents: [

                ]
            }
        }
     })
</script>
<style scoped>
    .card-title-docs {
        margin: 20px 20px;
    }

    .card-header {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #515151;
    }

    .card-sub-header {
        font-size: .8rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .7px;
        color: #7f818d;
    }
    .map-container{
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #us-map {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    path:hover, circle:hover {
        stroke: #002868 !important;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        fill: #002868 !important;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #path67 {
        fill: none !important;
        stroke: #A9A9A9 !important;
        cursor: default;
    }

    #info-box {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #BF0A30;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: arial;
    }
</style>
'''
```

Comment: CSS hovers can only effect the hovered element, or elements that come after it. This means self, children, later siblings, and later siblings' children. In your component, `#info-box` comes before your `svg`, thus, CSS hover selectors cannot change its properties. To have a pure CSS solution, you would need `#info-box` to be inside your `svg`, which may not be what you want. A Vue solution, however, would work just fine.

Comment: @Trevin Avery Yea some more digging made me realize a pure css solution is probably not practical. I am going to update my question. Is using pure javascript okay in vueJS methods?

Comment: Kind of. You should avoid using things like `document.getElementById()`, since there can be multiple instances of your component, or other components could have conflicting IDs. You should use `$refs`, and if you need to use vanilla javascript, just get the element from the component with `$el` (e.g. `this.$refs.infoBox.$el`). Adding event listeners is just fine. Make sure to add them in `mounted()` and also remove them in `beforeDestroy()` or `destroyed()`.

Comment: @Trevin Avery I have adjusted my code to instead use hover since it seems VueJS mousemove is a bit inconsistent to just doing a click event. I have updated my question above. I need to get the top and left position of the path to display my info box. I tried this.offsetTop and this.offsetLeft and it returns undefined values. Is this because it is a path element?

Comment: I'm not sure why the offsets don't work. But `getBoundingClientRect()` does work. You can do this on the path to get the top left of the path in the view port. Then, since your `#info-box` is inside the `.map-container`, you need to adjust for the position of that container, or change the `#info-box` to a fixed position. To adjust for the position, simply use the `getBoundingClientRect()` function on the `.map-container` or the `#us-map`, then subtract the top and left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in the comments on the question.

In summary, the issue was understanding how to position the `#info-box` element. Using the `getBoundingClientRect()` function, we can get the position of any element relative to the entire document. To get the position of the clicked path element, simply subtract the top and left of the `#us-map` from the top and left of the path. This will give the position for the top left corner of the path, relative to the containing element. We can then use that to position the `#info-box`.